# DIV's reorder by themselves upon expand - how do I keep the same order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've got a grid of items that upon click expand to show a table below it. It works fine, but it reorders the DIV's positions as per my illustration below.

I need them to keep their respective position in their "columns".

Here's the illustration to make it clear:

[image]

And here is my HTML code:

```
<div 
class="item-component" 
ng-controller="CollapseCtrl"
ng-repeat="component in components.components | filter : components.filterByFilter | filter : searchText"
>

<div class="component-wrapper" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    Item - click to expand
</div>

<div class="codes-wrapper" collapse="isCollapsed">    
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        Expanded content here
    </table>    
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the .item-component class:

```
.item-component {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

How would I achieve the "expected result" in my illustration?

Comment: if you can create a fiddle that would help to address the problem more efficiently http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have to work with table instead of div

Comment: @anurupr I'm using AngularJS and have set my own directives to expand and collapse the DIVs. I figured an illustration would sufice since the problem is not that hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block`  instead of `float:left` on your `.item-component`

[**Living Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RA8Pr/3/)

```
.item-component {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Or, you can take a look at [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and do it by using the `:before` element maintaning the `float:left` as you had it before.
You would also need to wrap each row:

```
.col{
    float:left;
    width: 32.33%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
    display:block;
}
/* This do the trick */
.row:before{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Living example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RA8Pr/4/)

**Update**
If you don't want the gap you will have to look for another HTML markup. You will have to print first each column with each rows.

This is the needed html markup:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="row" id="demo">1</div>
    <div class="row">4</div>
    <div class="row">7</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="row">2</div>
    <div class="row">5</div>
    <div class="row">8</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="row">3</div>
    <div class="row">6</div>
    <div class="row">9</div>
</div>
```

And the needed css:

```
.col{
    float:left;
    width: 32.33%;
}
.row{
   display:block;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background: #ccc;
   min-height: 50px;
}
#demo{
    height: 150px;   
    background: red;
}
```

[**Living demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RA8Pr/6/)

Comment: That solves the reordering problem. Thanks for the answer! But in both your examples, there's a gap between the first row and the second below #2 and #3. Can't those stay in their original place?

Comment: Yea I'll need to use the last solution. Now I just need to find out how to iterate items the "angular way". Thanks again for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the following way.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.col').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('clicked')
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S7r3D/1/

ETA: the problem with this solution is that it moves entire row down. I don't really see how to nicely achieve what you want...You could try to overflow the other divs, but it depends on your needs. Is such solution acceptable?

ETA2: actually I made it perfect I think! Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/S7r3D/3/
The crucial change was rearranging divs and putting them in columns instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fleft">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fleft">
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fleft">
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">9</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    clear: both;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

.col.clicked {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

.fleft
{    
    float: left;
}
```

JS: `/* same as above */`

Comment: I figure the only way to make that gap go away is by adding and iterator to add HTML markup like the other answers suggested? If that's the case then I'd rather find out how to do that in AngularJS rather than having that gap. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: @pedropeixoto: I edited my answer, please check it. No gap anymore :-)

Comment: Yea, looks like I'll have to add an iterator to create new HTML markup. Thanks for the answer. I'll accept Alvaro's answer since the method being used is the same and he answered first. That's not to say I don't appreciate your help, I do. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Create three container divs, and afterwards, put {1, 4, 7} into div1, {2, 5, 8} into div2, and  {3, 6, 9} into div3.

Otherwise you will have it very difficult to control their positioning.